# Can't retrieve it in View here is my code snippet having stored data in session using SortedDictionary key value pair

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Compilation Error:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on
>   variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public
>   definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
<!-- namespace json.Controllers
    {
        public class DetailController : Controller {
            //
            // GET: /Detail/

            public ActionResult Index(){
                return View();
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public JsonResult SendQuery(string FirstName){
                string result = string.Empty;
                if (Session["entity"] == null){
                    SortedDictionary<string, string> s = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
                    s.Add("name",FirstName);


                    Session["entity"] = s;
                }
                else{
                    SortedDictionary<string, string> s = (SortedDictionary<string, string>)Session["entity"];
                    s.Add("name",FirstName);

                    Session["entity"] = s;
                }

                return Json(Session["entity"]);
            }    
        }
    }
-->

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="x" value="x" />

<button id="btnSendQuery">butt</button>
<pre id="datax"></pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnSendQuery").click(function () {
        var arrayOfdata = null;
        var url = '/Detail/SendQuery';
        var param = JSON.stringify({
            FirstName: $("#x").val(),
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: param,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    alert(data);

                }
                else {
                    alert("Error")
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
        //  }
    });
</script>

@{
    if (Session["entity"] != null){
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> s in Session["entity"]){
            @s.Key 
            @s.Value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Session stores values as the `Object` type. When you read the session value using `Session["entity"]` it returns the Object type. You cannot enumerate an object type variable. You need to explicitly cast it to a type which is enumeratable.

Cast it to `SortedDictionary<string, string>` and use that in your foreach loop.

```
@if (Session["entity"] != null)
{
    var items = (SortedDictionary<string, string>) Session["entity"];
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <p>@item.Key @item.Value</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot i . I overlooked that part may be :P ... Again thanks buddy :)